# Android: calling the application class of the library project

Tags: android

I have a library project which I am referencing from the main Android project. The library project has an Application class which is declared in the library's manifest like this,

```
< application android:name="com.textbook.pageview.BookApp"
```

I am declaring the same in the main project's manifest and everything works fine but what do I do if a project already has an application class specified in it's manifest. How do I call the library project's application class in that scenario? I get nullpointers if i don't, coz the application class does important settings and initializations for the library to function properly.

thx. 
Lucky

Answer (score 0):

Just add the library project with:

> Right click your project -> Properties -> Android -> Add Library.

Answer (score 0):

As @Edward van Raak said, you must reference the library project from the properties of the main project(both projects must be in the same workspace).

But also you will have to add the line `manifestmerger.enabled=true` in the file `project.properties` of the main project in order to merge the manifest files of both projects.

Comment: Thanks Niculare, but i have already added the reference to the main project and added whatever there is in the lib's manifest to the main's manifest. Every thing works fine till this point but once i remove the application class from the main's manifest things start to fall apart.  I am using this lib in different projects, some of them already have their own application class defined in their  manifest so i cannot define the lib's application class? Any clues how to resolve this?

Comment: You can not remove the `<application>` tag from the manifest of the main application. As I said before, let each project have it's own manifest file(each having a single `<application>` tag) and add the option `manifestmerger.enabled=true` to automatically merge the manifests.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I don't want to remove the `<application>` tag but remove   `< android:name="com.textbook.pageview.BookApp"` from main's `<application>` tag 

 

and possible keep it else where so that the main project can call it. I will try the `manifestmerger.enabled=true` property. 

thanks.

Comment: I think I didn't understand what you mean by "Application class". Is that the "<application>" tag from the manifest file?

Comment: I use the application class within my project and I also have a library that uses the application class. How can I use both. I can't delete any. Thankful. @niculare